# How to Intialize Database with entitycore in dotnet 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have written a class like bellow that should initialize the database

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using TvApi.Models;
using TvApi.Services;

namespace TvApi.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        static List<List<Cast>> listedCasts;
        static List<List<ShowCast>> listedShowCasts;
        static List<Show> listedShows;

        public static async Task InitializeAsync(TvMazeContext context)
        {
            for (long i= 1;i < 10; i++)
            {
                long ShowId = i;
                Show show = await Crawler.CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);
                listedShows.Add(show);
                List<Cast> casts = await Crawler.GetCastsAsync(ShowId);
                listedCasts.Add(casts);
                List<ShowCast> showCasts = new List<ShowCast>();
                foreach (var item in casts)
                {
                    showCasts.Add(new ShowCast(show.ShowId, item));
                }
                listedShowCasts.Add(showCasts);

            }

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            if (context.shows.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            
            foreach (Show s in listedShows)
            {
                context.shows.Add(s);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            foreach (List<Cast> castsList in listedCasts)
            {
                foreach(Cast cast in castsList)
                {
                    context.casts.Add(cast);
                }

            }

            foreach (List<ShowCast> showCastsList in listedShowCasts)
            {
                foreach (ShowCast showCast in showCastsList)
                {
                    context.showCasts.Add(showCast);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am following the microsoft tutorial bellow to add the intializer to my startup.cs

[Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

However the program.cs there is different than mine:

```
//My version of program.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TvApi.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

//Database
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TvMazeContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

/*
 * My attempt to initialize
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();



IHost host; 
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<TvMazeContext>();
        await DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
    }
}
*/

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

What should I add to my version of the program.cs to correctly initialize my database during the startup?

Comment: First, you should add `context.SaveChanges();` after you modified the Database Context (ie: at the end of `InitializeAsync`)

Comment: Second, you are creating the Database every time you start the program regardless of whether the Database was created or not. Unless you dropped it manually, it will have conflict.

Comment: Third, consider using migrations instead of `"DbInitializer"` like this so that the Database is created for only one time and maintained automatically instead of dropping and then creating the Database everytime the program start. [Learn more about migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you question, I think You want to seed data in database, So here is a simple demo can fit .Net6 and .Net7

```
public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static async Task InitializeAsync(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            List<SeedModel> seedDatas = new List<SeedModel>();
            seedDatas.Add(new SeedModel()
            {
                Name = "AAAA",
                Age = 2
            });
            seedDatas.Add(new SeedModel()
            {
                Name = "BBB",
                Age = 3
            });
            seedDatas.Add(new SeedModel()
            {
                Name = "AAAA",
                Age = 2
            });

            await context.SeedModels.AddRangeAsync(seedDatas);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
    }
```

Then in `program.cs`

```
//.......    
var app = builder.Build();    
//.....
   
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    //Resolve dbcontext with DI help
    var dbcontext = (ApplicationDbContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));

    //call your static method herer

    await DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(dbcontext);
}
//......
```

Now, When you start your project, Database will be initialized with some data.

[image]